# Windows 2003/2008 Domain Controller Audit Policy

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, domain-controller

On Windows 2003/2008 domain controller:

1. Do you have to turn on audit policy in order to see user logon/logoff information  (success or failure, time & account name) in the event logs?
2. Are audit policies on by default on Windows 2003/2008 DC? By "on", I mean auditing (success/failure) for user logon/logoff information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes
2. No

You're Welcome